# Depreciation ++ operator in Swift 3, Looking for a work around

Tags: swift, properties, sprite-kit, operators, ios9

I currently use this as a game over counter.. 
GameScene Swift

```
var gameOverCounter = 0
```

it is called when a player runs hits an enemy (no physics bodies involved) 
touches began method

```
gameOverCounter++
if gameOverCounter > 3 {
    numRounds = 121
    // ...
}
```

same for number of rounds, and I am sure theres is plenty of people that use it for scoring...

```
score++
```

just curious for work arounds in relation to the topic, or if theres a better way to populate incremental value of there properties and achieve the same behavior.

Comment: `gameOverCounter += 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i += 1
```

Is the same as

```
i++
```

But it's more explicit and obvious

Comment: Here is some more information on why it was deprecated: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0004-remove-pre-post-inc-decrement.md